# How to Add column in a Queried Datatable and append data

Tags: vb.net

I have queried data table named `dt`. Now I want to add a additional column named PriorityIndex and values will be based on two of the queried columns and then value assignment.

After that I would like to sort with different criteria.

```
strSQL = "Some working text"
dt = GetData(Con, strSQL) ' Function to execute query
```

After that I am calculating and assigning new values as:

```
If ddlQtrTypePriority.SelectedItem.Value > dt.Rows(Row).Item(16) Then
    PriorityIndex = 1
ElseIf ddlQtrTypePriority.SelectedItem.Value < dt.Rows(Row).Item(16) Then
    PriorityIndex = 2
Else
    PriorityIndex = 3
End If
```

Now this PriorityIndex is to be appended in DataTable `dt` and overall data be sorted based on PriorityIndex values.

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: strSQL = "Some working text"
 dt = GetData(Con, strSQL) ‘ Function to execute query

After that I am Calculating and assigning new values as:

If ddlQtrTypePriority.SelectedItem.Value > dt.Rows(Row).Item(16) Then
       PriorityIndex = 1
ElseIf ddlQtrTypePriority.SelectedItem.Value < dt.Rows(Row).Item(16) Then
       PriorityIndex = 2
Else
       PriorityIndex = 3
End If

Now this PriorityIndex is to be appended in DataTable dt and overall data be sorted based on PriorityIndex Values.

Comment: For Testing Purpose Now I am doing